# Unit Testing ViewResult in Asp.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4

Even though there are couple of Posts on StackOverflow about Unit Testing Action Result in MVC, I have a specific Question ....

Here is my ActionResult in Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Products.ToList());
}
```

Every Item in Products has different attributes like Name,Photo,Quantity etc..
I wrote a testmethod for this method .It looks as follows :

```
private CartEntity db = new CartEntity();

[TestMethod]
public void Test_Index()
{
    //Arrange
    ProductsController prodController = new ProductsController();

    ViewResult = prodController.Index();


}
```

What Should I compare in this case since there are no parameters are being passed into Index Action

Comment: According to your code `Index()` returns a `ViewResult` and not a `RedirectToRouteResult` so I am confused as to both your unit test code and your question.

Comment: Hey @Igor, Thanks ..My actual code is wrong

Comment: `Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(RedirectToRouteResult));` will still fail according to your latest update. `Index` still returns a `ViewResult`

Comment: @Igor I think he wants a string there... `result` is a string if it comes out tof the key value dictionary for routing metadta

Comment: 1. You can test the model being passed to the `ViewResult`. 2. you can test the action method name is either empty or "Index". 3. You can test that the returned type is of type `ViewResult`.

Comment: Hey @tacos_tacos_tacos, I was passing Products type into the view which is being returned in Index Action.

Comment: You are not mocking your db, so that's not an Unit test, but an Integration Test. You can check `db.Products.ToList()` against `routeResult.ViewData.Model`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check out the [ViewResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewresult(v=vs.118).aspx) class, this can show you what else you could test.
What you need to do is mock your `DbContext` and supply it with data in the `Products` property (`DbSet<>`) as this is being called in your controller's action.
You can then test

1. The type being returned
2. The model on the ViewResult
3. The ViewName which should be empty or Index

Sample code

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_Index()
{
    //Arrange
    ProductsController prodController = new ProductsController(); // you should mock your DbContext and pass that in

    // Act
    var result = prodController.Index() as ViewResult;

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    Assert.IsNotNull(result.Model); // add additional checks on the Model
    Assert.IsTrue(string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.ViewName) || result.ViewName == "Index");
}
```

---

If you need help mocking a DbContext there are existing frameworks and articles on this subject. Here is one from Microsoft titled [Testing with a mocking framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429.aspx). Ideally you should be injecting your dependencies (including DbContext instances) into the constructors of your `Controller` instances using a DI framework like AutoFac or Unity or NInject (the list goes on). This also makes unit testing much easier.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is much more helpful to me..Thank you

Comment: I tried this `var result = prodController.Index() as ViewResult;` still getting null result ? any clue?

Comment: @Neo - Not without seeing the return statement inside your `Index` method. I would recommend asking a new question on [so] instead of trying to solve it in the comments though.

Comment: using same code
`public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Products.ToList());
}`

Comment: If you want to access any of the model's properties remember to cast the result.Model, so: var myModel = (MyModel)result.Model;